# Cannot enter data into tables with inter related foreign keys

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, sql-insert

I have created the tables with following code, but the foreign key constraints does not allow data addition. What can I do to solve this problem?

```
CREATE TABLE Employee(
Ssn VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
BDate DATE,
FName VARCHAR(25),
MInit VARCHAR(5),
LName VARCHAR(25),
Address VARCHAR(40),
Sex VARCHAR(6),
Salary INT,
SupervisorSsn VARCHAR(10),
DNumber INT
);
CREATE TABLE

CREATE TABLE Department(
DNumber INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
DName VARCHAR(15),
MgrSsn VARCHAR(10),
MgrStartDate DATE,
NumberofEmployees INT,
CONSTRAINT Department_MgrSsn_FK FOREIGN KEY(MgrSsn) REFERENCES Employee(Ssn) ON DELETE SET DEFAULT ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

ALTER TABLE Employee
ADD CONSTRAINT Employee_SupervisorSsn_FK FOREIGN KEY(SupervisorSsn) REFERENCES Employee(Ssn) ON DELETE SET DEFAULT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
ADD CONSTRAINT Employee_DNumber_FK FOREIGN KEY(DNumber) REFERENCES Department(DNumber) ON DELETE SET DEFAULT ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: Why wouldn't that allow to insert rows? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f6eb218010190a115179c6e440ad01c1

Comment: Due to inter-related foreign key constraints

Comment: Not sure what you mean, inserts work just fine: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f6eb218010190a115179c6e440ad01c1

Comment: But you are not entering data for foreign keys right?
For example, DNumber in Employee

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5499fe81c499c8ab39d5e904a8e1cf5d

Comment: In entering data in to Department, you are not entering for mgrssn
Is that the only way to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do that in Postgres.

#### Update later

The most obvious one: insert `null` values firs, then update it later:

```
insert into department 
  (dnumber, dname)
values 
  (1, 'One'),
  (2, 'Two'),
  (3, 'Three');

insert into employee (ssn, fname, lname, supervisorssn, dnumber)
values 
  ('123', 'Arthur', 'Dent', '456', 1),
  ('456', 'Ford', 'Prefect', null, 2),
  ('789', 'Zaphod', 'Beeblebrox', null, 3);

update department
  set mgrssn = '456'
where dnumber in (1,2);

update department
  set mgrssn = '789'
where dnumber = 3;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2d4cd1f917b21a740732a8fae7f16124)

#### Deferred constraints

Make the constraints deferred, so that they will be checked at the end of the transaction, rather when running the INSERT:

```
ALTER TABLE department
  add constraint fk_dempt2emp foreign key (mgrssn) references employee
  deferrable initially deferred; --<<
```

Then you can insert the rows in any order you like as long as everything happens in a single transaction:

```
begin transaction; --<< important!

insert into department 
  (dnumber, dname, mgrssn)
values 
  (1, 'One', '456'),
  (2, 'Two', '456'),
  (3, 'Three', '789')

insert into employee (ssn, fname, lname, supervisorssn, dnumber)
values 
  ('123', 'Arthur', 'Dent', '456', 1),
  ('456', 'Ford', 'Prefect', null, 2),
  ('789', 'Zaphod', 'Beeblebrox', null, 3);

commit; -- the FKs will be checked here
```

#### Do everything in a single statement

You can use a [data modifying CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) to insert rows into two tables. As this is evaluated as a single statement, the constraints do not need to be deferrable.

```
with new_depts as (
  insert into department 
    (dnumber, dname, mgrssn)
  values 
    (1, 'One', '456'),
    (2, 'Two', '456'),
    (3, 'Three', '789')
)
insert into employee (ssn, fname, lname, supervisorssn, dnumber)
values 
  ('123', 'Arthur', 'Dent', '456', 1),
  ('456', 'Ford', 'Prefect', null, 2),
  ('789', 'Zaphod', 'Beeblebrox', null, 3)
;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c3739579a38cf01167a06a89e046361b)